# Group by with varchars and null values

Tags: mysql

I need some help. I have a pretty big table with account information and invoices. The table was built in a per-invoice method, meaning that if a customer has several invoices pending, there will be as many lines as invoices pending. I need to 'turn it around'. I need to have a single 'line' per customer and have all invoice information as added columns (additional to the customer's personal information that is also there). I have managed to create a view that will display the info in an orderly fashion kinda' way:

```
+------------------------------------------------+---------------------+-------------+
| cust  | invoice1            | invoice2            | invoice3 | invoice4 | invoice5 |
+------------------------------------------------+---------------------+-------------+
| Lady  | 1000000000002069080 | NULL                | NULL     | NULL     | NULL     |
| Lady  | NULL                | 1000000000001957290 | NULL     | NULL     | NULL     |
| Boy   | 1000000000002116078 | NULL                | NULL     | NULL     | NULL     |
| Gent  | 1000000000002068468 | NULL                | NULL     | NULL     | NULL     |
| Waldo | 1000000000002094726 | NULL                | NULL     | NULL     | NULL     |
| Waldo | NULL                | 1000000000002097744 | NULL     | NULL     | NULL     |
| John  | NULL                | 1000000000001991541 | NULL     | NULL     | NULL     |
| John  | 1000000000002104255 | NULL                | NULL     | NULL     | NULL     |
| Peter | 1000000000002066307 | NULL                | NULL     | NULL     | NULL     |
| Peter | NULL                | 1000000000001954615 | NULL     | NULL     | NULL     |
+-------+---------------------+---------------------+----------+----------+----------+
```

I need the end result to be like this:

```
+------------------------------------------------+---------------------+-------------+
| cust  | invoice1            | invoice2            | invoice3 | invoice4 | invoice5 |
+------------------------------------------------+---------------------+-------------+
| Lady  | 1000000000002069080 | 1000000000001957290 | NULL     | NULL     | NULL     |
| Boy   | 1000000000002116078 | NULL                | NULL     | NULL     | NULL     |
| Gent  | 1000000000002068468 | NULL                | NULL     | NULL     | NULL     |
| Waldo | 1000000000002094726 | 1000000000002097744 | NULL     | NULL     | NULL     |
| John  | 1000000000002104255 | 1000000000001991541 | NULL     | NULL     | NULL     |
| Peter | 1000000000002066307 | 1000000000001954615 | NULL     | NULL     | NULL     |
+-------+---------------------+---------------------+----------+----------+----------+
```

But I don't know how to use a GROUP BY tha can help me as the values are set as varchar and cannot use SUM to add the fields, which was a suggestion I read somewhere around here.

Here is the 'table' (view) definition:

```
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field          | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| cust           | varchar(100) | YES  |     |         |       |
| invoice1       | varchar(25)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| invoice2       | varchar(25)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| invoice3       | varchar(25)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| invoice4       | varchar(25)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| invoice5       | varchar(25)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

How can I put these fields together in a query that is not too heavy? I wave around 100k records that I need to operate on. Any suggestions?

I'm using MySQL and MyISAM as engine and I changing the SQL engine is not an option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
SELECT
    tbl.cust,
    MAX(tbl.invoice1) AS invoice1,
    MAX(tbl.invoice2) AS invoice2,
    MAX(tbl.invoice3) AS invoice3,
    MAX(tbl.invoice4) AS invoice4,
    MAX(tbl.invoice5) AS invoice5
FROM
    Table1 as tbl
GROUP BY
    tbl.cust
```

**Update**

M Khalid Junaid : was kind to supply a sql fiddler [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7c2ff/3)

**Edit**

You can also think about if you want to use `MIN` or `MAX`. If you have just one `invoice` per `cust`. Then a `MIN` aggregate will give the same output like this:

```
SELECT
    tbl.cust,
    MIN(tbl.invoice1) AS invoice1,
    MIN(tbl.invoice2) AS invoice2,
    MIN(tbl.invoice3) AS invoice3,
    MIN(tbl.invoice4) AS invoice4,
    MIN(tbl.invoice5) AS invoice5
FROM
    Table1 as tbl
GROUP BY
    tbl.cust
```

Comment: [**this fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7c2ff/3)  proves your answer is correct +1

Answer (score 0):

I like to use IFNULL to handle null values like so:

```
select cust, 
  sum(ifnull(invoice1,0)) i1, 
  sum(ifnull(invoice2,0)) i2, 
  sum(ifnull(invoice3,0)) i3, 
  sum(ifnull(invoice4,0)) i4, 
  sum(ifnull(invoice5,0)) i5
from table
group by cust;
```

If you don't want to add invoices, then you can list them by so (null values won't be included):

```
select cust, 
  group_concat(invoice1) i1, 
  group_concat(invoice2) i2, 
  group_concat(invoice3) i3, 
  group_concat(invoice4) i4, 
  group_concat(invoice5) i5
from table
group by cust;
```